# libvlc 3.0.0 is not saving anymore a stream to file

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I am working on a project involving libvlc.

Until now, I have been using the 2.2.x stable branch. But I strongly need two features that made me pass to libvlc 3.0.0 (nightly build May 27 2017): grab a frame from an mp4 file and stream a list of files to RTP. Both of these features deadlock using libvlc 2.2.5.1.

Now I am a little baffled: a feature that used to work well in libvlc 2.2.5.1 is not working anymore. That is, saving an RTSP stream into an MP4 file.

The code would be like this:

```
const char * const args1[] = {
    "--sout", transcode.c_str(),
    msecDelay.c_str()
};
size_t argsCount1 = sizeof(args1) / sizeof(args1[0]);

it->second.p_lib = libvlc_new(argsCount, p_args);
```

with the string named transcode like:

```
transcode = "#transcode{acodec=mp3}:duplicate{ dst=file{ dst=" + string(it->second.fDump) + " }, dst=display }";
```

Now, when I execute the same code with libvlc 3.0.0 I can see the video, alas no file.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Antonio

Comment: got the same issue, have you solved this?

Comment: No, I am sorry. At the end I used libvlc 2.2.6 and changed the architecture of the application, just recording to file in separated coprocesses. The application was threaded before this modification.I guess that a bit of investigation would have solved the problem, just starting VLC and looking at the transcode string in "File/Convert".